# How can I ensure I annotate each Kubernetes node before Pods are scheduled to it on EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, cni

I am trying to use [CNI Custom Networking on EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-custom-network.html) to make sure that Pod IPs are allocated from alternative subsets (to prevent IP starvation in the subnets my cluster nodes are running in). To do this I need to create some ENIConfigs and annotate each node.

How can I ensure that each node is annotated before any Pods are scheduled to it to ensure no Pod IPs are allocated from the subnets my nodes are running in?

EDIT: The only solution I can think of so far is:

- Add a NoSchedule taint to all nodes by default
- Deploy a custom controller that tolerates the taint
- Get the controller to annotate all nodes as required and remove the taint

However, if the above is the only workaround that is a lot of effort for a managed service

Answer (score 1):

How about:

- Add a `ENIConfigComplete: false` taint to all nodes by default
- Deploy DaemonSet that tolerates `ENIConfigComplete: false`
- DaemonSet creates a pod on each new node which
- creates some ENIConfigs on the node (bash script??)
- annotates each node with `ENIConfigComplete: true`
- DaemonSet no longer tolerates the node, so
- Pod is removed from the node.

The DaemonSet would ensure that every new node was properly set up.

Salesforce talk about this technique for provisioning the disks on their new nodes:

- https://engineering.salesforce.com/provisioning-kubernetes-local-persistent-volumes-61a82d1d06b0

It would avoid having a long running controller process.

Comment: Yeah that could work and would avoid a controller (ENIConfigs could be created ahead of time as well) - only thing I'm not sure on is how you would get all the other Pods to tolerate that taint so they could schedule? So the edit I would make is to remove the taint